# How Do I make my HTML searchable by a browser Ctrl-F and use absolute text positioning?

Tags: html, css

Normally if I had an HTML File, I would be able to search for "Three little pigs." by Ctrl F, I could style the whole sentence any way I wanted, i.e.:

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 362px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three little pigs.</span>
```

But If I wanted the words in different colors, styles, etc. then I can't search the page anymore. Once I hit space after "Three" the search fails.

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 362px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three </span>

<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 380px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:18px;">little </span>

<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 391px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:17px;">pigs.</span>
```

How do I make all of the words styled in specific absolute locations, but still a single string?

Comment: Ctrl-F in editor or browser?

Comment: If you remove `position: absolute;` then the browser able to find `Three little pigs.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally if I had an HTML File, I would be able to search for "Three little pigs." by Ctrl F, I could style the whole sentence any way I wanted, i.e.:

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 362px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three little pigs.</span>
```

It is because even you have assigned `position: absolute` in the style above you have those three letters inline and the absolute positioning works for all of them at the same time not for a single word.

But when coming onwards the below code

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 362px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three </span>
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 380px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:18px;">little </span>
<span style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 391px; color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:17px;">pigs.</span>
```

Here you have `position:absolute` for all three words separately and it gives the result as

[image]

And because of this formation by absolute positioning `Ctrl + F` can't find the words correctly and eventually after searching only the first word(**Three**)  it fails.

**Solution**

Remove the `position:absolute` styles for all of them

```
<span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three </span>
<span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:18px;">little </span>
<span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:17px;">pigs.</span>
```

Comment: I was worried that the absolute positioning would be the downfall. I think what we're trying to acomplish can still be done on the front-end side, but the back-end HTML gen doesn't look like it can get much better. Thanks. Awarding Bounty when it allows.

Comment: Yes it is true that backend won't make any difference.

Comment: @SetSlapShot please can you tell me why i haven't been awarded the bounty, eager to know?:(

Comment: This is the alt text when I hover over the +200 button. I will in 21 more hours when the system permits me my helpful friend! :)

            <button class="c-not-allowed grid--cell s-btn s-btn__unset o70 h:o100 f:o100"
                    data-award-if-applied="200"
                    title="You may award your bounty worth 200 reputation in 21 hours">
                <div class="s-badge s-badge__bounty s-badge__sm bg-black-500">+200</div>
            </button>

Comment: Can you please give it a try now for bounty.

Answer (score 2):

In a very specific situation (where you don’t need to scroll, and the container is bigger than the children), you can swap out `position: absolute` for `position: sticky`. This lets you find in the page as you’re expecting but also gives you the ability to position your words as you want.

Answer (score 1):

With `position: absolute` on each `span` element it isn't possible.
A possible Solution would be to use a wrapper element like `div` and give it the absolute position

```html
<div style="position: absolute; top: 163px; left: 362px;">
    <span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:15px;">Three </span>
    <span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:18px;">little </span>
    <span style="color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.01); font-size:17px;">pigs.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using position relative, you can still move your elements around: (and the combined string is searchable). I have changed it to four to be the only string in the page.

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  color: blue;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  color: red;
}

.c {
position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="a">Four </span>

<span class="b">little </span>

<span class="c">pigs.</span>
```